# Need help outputting long string

Tags: c++

When I use `cout` for very long string it does not output the entire string, only the end.

```
std::string test[] = {"alotof text--sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsfsdferer----248 characters"};
std::cout << *test << std::endl;
```

output: er----248 characters

*which is the end of the string only, most of the beginning was cut off*

Comment: What happens when you use a string instead of an array of strings?

Comment: It shouldn't matter since the pointer is pointing to the first element of the array, which would be his string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the output to a file and check whether the content is in the file. I would guess that your string contains carriage return (`'\r'`) characters which cause the position of the output to be moved to the front of the line, visually overwriting the characters already written on this line. All characters should, however, be visible in the file.

Comment: TY you are correct, I was not using the string in example did not think about how much it would effect it.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::string test[] = {"alotof text--sdfsdfsdfsddfasdfsdfasdfadfadfadfadfdfadfadfadfadfadfadfadsfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfafdasdfadsfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadsfasdfasdfadsfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadsfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadsafsdffsdfsfsdferer----248 characters"};
    std::cout << test[0].length() << std::endl;
    std::cout << *test << std::endl;
}
```

here was my output:

```
336
alotof text--    sdfsdfsdfsddfasdfsdfasdfadfadfadfadfadfadfadfadfadfadfadfadsfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfafdasdfadsfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadsfasdfasdfadsfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadsfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadsafsdffsdfsfsdferer----248 characters
```

Doesn't seem to be anything wrong with it

Comment: There are certain variables you have to take into account. Just because it's working according to you does not mean it works for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with Visual Studio 2010 C++ compiler, and code exactly as you wrote and my output was:

```
335
alotof text--sdfsdfsdfsddfasdfsdfasdfadfadfadfadfdfadfadfadfadfadfadfadsfasdfasdfasdfasdfa
sdfafdasdfadsfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadsfasdfasdfadsfasdf
asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadsfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfas
dfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadsafsdffsdfsfsdferer----248 characters
```

Works fine for me.